# How to extract tabular data from pdf?

Tags: data-mining

I have a requirement where I need build a solution to extract information from multiple pdfs.
The information is stored in tabular format in pdf files. The tables are not very well structured and each pdf document has different format of tables.
The pdfs consist of a lot of pages with text and tables.

I tried [Tabula](https://tabula.technology/), but it didn't produce a satisfactory result. Thought about using [pdfminer](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/) as well, but it looks very cumbersome to me.

Can you suggest more ideas and tools to solve this problem?

Comment: what platform are you on R, Python...?

Comment: try algodocs.com

Answer (score 0):

For some literature on the problem you may want to look at https://medium.com/sap-machine-learning-research/chargrid-77aa75e6d605 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.08799

For a commercially available solution [Textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) and [Tika](https://tika.apache.org/) come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Pdfminer, 
Pypdf2,
Camelot,
Tika,
OCR,
Tesseract,
Textract,
Nuance OCR

These are a few pdf parsing tools.